# Making a css class conditional on a textbox control being in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have a textbox control (txtL_DATE_DISCHARGE) in an update panel which is a date field. To this I have applied a jquery datepicker via the css class date. I have managed to shift the focus to the other textbox control on the page (txtLenEpisode) but on page load the datepicker dialog appears automatically, and this is despite commenting out the updatepanel altogether. Is there a way of making the date class conditional on the cursor being in the textbox - I believe this is an event? I'm happy to do this in jquery or javascript or vb.net.

```
<asp:Content ID="contentMainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMainContent" runat="Server">
<div class="palliativeContainer contentContainer">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table id="tblPalDischarge" class="dataEntryTable fullWidth spaceTop" runat="server">
                <tr id="trL_DATE_DISCHARGE" runat="server">
                    <td id="tdlblL_DATE_DISCHARGE" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblL_DATE_DISCHARGE" runat="server" Text="Date of Discharge"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td id="tdtxtL_DATE_DISCHARGE" runat="server">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtL_DATE_DISCHARGE" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="none" />
                        <input type="button" id="btnDischDate" runat="server" value="T" class="Tbuttons" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="trLengthEpisode" runat="server">
                    <td id="tdlblLengthEpisode" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLengthEpisode" runat="server" Text="Length of Care Episode"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td id="td4" runat="server">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLenEpisode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: What about CSS3 pseudo class: `:focus` ?

Comment: @A. Wolff I've tried this but to no effect $('#<%= txtLenEpisode.ClientID %>').focus();

Comment: How have you turned on the datepicker to the class? The datepicker would not normally come on until the field has focus.

Comment: Also how did you "shift focus" . i think the key here is that the date tb does have focus on page_load